# Google api request limits

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I have a question about the Google API limits.
E.g.

> The Google Places API for Android enforces a default limit of 1,000
>   requests per 24 hour period. If your app exceeds the limit, the app
>   will start failing.

This limit is **per** device right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. From this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#UsageLimits

> The daily usage is calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side requests combined.

This leads me to believe it's based on the API key, not a per client basis.

Also note you can increase this limit without paying extra:

> Verify your identity to get 150,000 free requests per 24 hour period, by enabling billing on the Google API Console. A credit card is required for verification. **We ask for your credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Google Places API Web Service.**

Comment: So if I have an app with 500 users and I e.g launch a place picker then it can be launched only **twice** per user **per day**? That is not useful at all then. Or am I missing something?

Comment: See my update, that should help out your quota limit. For a large scale app you'll need the premium plan however

Comment: I read about that but that doesn't make sense. On the top of the page it says: `It is important to Google that developers have access to as much capacity as they need to be successful,`. This means that the api is only useful for only an app with less than 100 users. For 100 users it can be used only 10 times per day which is similar to nothing. Is it really per key!!!!

Comment: What are the client-side and server-side requests in the context of android?

Comment: I think it would just be any request (from a client or any server you have) that uses the same API key

Comment: Still it could take into account the device. It can distinguish between devices per request right?

Comment: It most definitely would be able to tell which device is sending which request, but when it comes to the rate limit, I'm fairly certain its based on your API key.

Comment: But then this API is of no use except for a hello world app. Am I missing something?

Comment: The 150,000 limit seems rather generous to me, if that doesn't suit your needs you can pay for more

Comment: Ah that one is free even if billing is on? Didn't realize that

Comment: Still it is 100 requests per day for an app with 1000 users